# Prepros-prepend like function for grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, concatenation

You know how with PrePros you can go `// @prepros-prepend "jquery.js"` And it'll include jQuery there. I have for instance a website.js that get's included in all my html files, and then with the help of yepnope I include certain plugins as they are needed, for instance, say I have a lightbox on the homepage only but not on any other page, then id like to have a lightbox.js file that includes all the libraries (except jquery) needed to to run the lightbox on that js file. Like i know it could cause libraries being loaded twice etc, but that's besides the point. What I want to know is what Grunt tasks and workflow do I need to run to achieve this? Like ideally I would like // @gurnt-include 'lightbox.js' and it'll include that file right there, then run it through Closure Compiler and inject into a directory.

TL:DR;
Grunt task to concat files inline with comment.

Comment: It may be grunt-usemin, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall I cant use grunt-usemin, because my html is generated with PHP.